# Compilation error reqwest::get(url).status()

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am trying to fetch web data in rust by utilizing the reqwest library.  I have created the project with Cargo However, whenever I try to compile the code I am getting an error:

```
7 |     let mut response = reqwest::get(url).status();
  |                                          ^^^^^^ method not found in `impl std::future::Future`
```

It seems like a simple error--maybe I'm just forgetting about some syntax somewhere.  I don't know why it keeps referring to that standard library.

```
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate select;
extern crate scraper;
extern crate tokio;

fn get_website(url: &str) {
    let mut response = reqwest::get(url).status();

    //print!("{:?}\n", response.status());
}

fn main() {
    let url = "https://google.com";

    get_website(&url);
}
```

my Cargo.toml file dependencies looks like:

```
[dependencies] 
reqwest = "0.10.4" 
select = "0.4.3" 
scraper = "0.12.0" 
tokio = {version = "0.2.21", features = ["full"]}
```

Comment: The latest versions of reqwest return a `Future`, so you need to handle it before retrieving the outcome.

Comment: The linked answer is a basic template you can use. you only need to return the `status` instead of the `text`. The error is informing you that `get` returns a `Future` and that the future doesn't have a `status` method on it. The `Response` that's returned after `await`ing the future has it.

Comment: this makes a lot more sense.  I didn't realize that in the new versions it was handled this way.  I must have been looking at old examples.